Scroll action not working in BrowserStack, but works locally in Appium script
I am using Appium for mobile automation and have implemented a scrolling mechanism in my test scripts. While the scroll actions work fine locally on my Android emulator, they fail to execute properly when running on BrowserStack. I'm using the following methods for scrolling:
scrollToText method:
  public void scrollToText(String text) {
     driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new          UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"" + text + "\"))"));
  }

scrollUp method:
  public void scrollUp() {
    boolean canScrollMore;
    do {
        canScrollMore = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile:  scrollGesture", ImmutableMap
            .of("left", 100, "top", 100, "width", 200, "height", 200, "direction", "up", "percent", 3.0));
    } while (canScrollMore);
  }

scrollAndView method:
public void scrollAndView(String visibleText) {
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"" + visibleText + "\").instance(0))"));
} 

The problem is that the scroll action works fine on my local setup but fails on BrowserStack.
The elements are not scrolled to as expected, and I don't get any errors or exceptions.

Add this capability to use 2.X Appium version
"browserstack.appiumVersion" : "2.6.0"
You can use this capability generator to get the caps as per your language.
